# My values are changing by changing the position of methods

Tags: c#

I'm working on c# to make a program for checking vowels,consonants,characters,words and number of sentences using method for each)
.  My program is  working good but my
problem is changing the places of method where I applied them chance the values.

Here is the program
on method **characters** I use the method words (whick basically counts the spaces ) same for **Consonants**

*the problem is I need to apply the methods on main accourding to the order I have created them* "***Words>Sentences>Vowels>Characters>COnsonants***"
If I chnage the order I get the wrong answer

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Task_Raza_Class
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string state;
        Console.WriteLine("Enter an Statement / Sentance \nPress Enter to Continue..");
        state = Console.ReadLine();

        raza task = new raza();
        // Words>Sentances>Vowels>Characters>COnsonents
        Console.WriteLine("Words"+task.words(state));
        Console.WriteLine("No of Sentances"+task.tances(state));
        Console.WriteLine("Vowels"+task.vowels(state));
        Console.WriteLine("Characters"+task.characters(state));
        Console.WriteLine("Consonents"+task.consonents(state));


        Console.ReadKey();
    }
  }
}
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Task_Raza_Class
{
class raza
{
    public  int cw , cv , cc , cp , cchar ;

    public raza()
    {
        cw = 1; cv = cc = cp = cchar = 0;

    }
    public int words(string state)
    {
        char[] s_arr = new char[200];
        s_arr = state.ToCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < s_arr.Length; i++)
        {
            if(s_arr[i]==' ')
            {
                cw++;
            }
        }
        return (cw);
    }
    public int tances(string state)
    {
        char[] s_arr = new char[200];
        s_arr = state.ToCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < s_arr.Length; i++)
        {
            if (s_arr[i] == '.')
            {
                cp++;
            }
        }
        return (cp);
    }
    public int vowels(string state)
    {
        char[] s_arr = new char[200];
        s_arr = state.ToCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < s_arr.Length; i++)
        {
            if (s_arr[i] == 'a' || s_arr[i] == 'A' || s_arr[i] == 'e' || s_arr[i] == 'E' || s_arr[i] == 'i' || s_arr[i] == 'I' || s_arr[i] == 'o' || s_arr[i] == 'O' || s_arr[i] == 'u' || s_arr[i] == 'U')
            {
                cv++;
            }
        }
        return (cv);
    }
    public int characters(string state)
    {
        char[] s_arr = new char[200];
        s_arr = state.ToCharArray();
        cchar = s_arr.Lenght - words(state)-1
        return (cchar);
    }
    public int consonents(string state)
    {
        char[] s_arr = new char[200];
        s_arr = state.ToCharArray();
        cc = characters(state)-vowels(state);
        return (cc);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: have you used the debugger to step thru the code..? can you tell us what you are getting vs what your expected outcome your are looking for..

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `cchar` and `cv` are member fields, whose values are maintained between calls. Because `consonents` calls `characters` and `vowels`, those two functions get called twice and on the 2nd time will have whatever value was left over from the first call.  There's no need for any member fields in your `raza` class - they can all be local variables.  Alternatively, you could design `raza` to accept the `state` parameter in the constructor, then call `characters` and `consonents` and change `vowels` to reuse the values from `cchar` and `cv`.

(BTW the correct English spelling is "consonants" and "sentences")